# How to pan and then immediately pinch with hammer js?

Tags: gesture, hammer.js, pan, pinch

I'm using hammerjs like this

```js
this.hammer = new Hammer.Manager(this.canvas);
const pinch = new Hammer.Pinch();
const pan = new Hammer.Pan({
  threshold: 5,
});
this.hammer.add([pinch, pan]);
```

But if I start panning I can't do a pinch.

When I mean pan and then pinch I mean, put one finger and pan, keep that finger on, add another finger and pinch. Note that you never remove the first finger.